# install canon printer mb5000

Tags: printing

I want to install a LAN printer on ubuntu 14.04 LTS: Canon Maxify MB5000.
CUPS finds the printer but I can't find any suitable driver when installing with CUPS (I chose one of another printer).
Is there any?

When I want to print a test page, nothing prints. The printing task disappears after a few second without any error.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Canon UK provides Linux drivers for MB5040 and MB5050, probably worth a try.

https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/maxify_mb_series/maxify_mb5050.aspx?type=drivers&language=&os=Linux%20(64-bit)

This driver works for our MB2300 series.

Comment: I have installed it. But I have the same problem.

Comment: Can you ping the printer?

Comment: I can't find the ip of the printer (network report from the printer doesn't show it). But as my computer can find it on  the LAN I guess the ping should work

Comment: It's been a while since I set this up, but I had to set a fixed IP for the printer in my router, then change the URI in the printer setup from cnijbe2://Canon/?port=net&serial=[MAC address] to ipp://[LAN ip of printer] to get it to work consistently.

Comment: thanx man...that worked. I will explain the steps.

Answer (score 1):

My printer was MB5300

[click here to Download IJ Printer Driver Ver. 5.00 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)](https://support-in.canon-asia.com/contents/IN/EN/0100626502.html)

Then exctacted it.

cd to folder

```
cd cnijfilter2-5.00-1-deb

sudo ./install.sh
```

Without closing the terminal

open printer in ubuntu > clicked add printer.

It automatically selected the driver and printed sample page.